# Recommended approach for triggering PageModel refresh

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a [FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) Xam Forms project that has a Settings page for capturing username and password. If the username or password changes I want to refresh the content of a WebView in the main page.

I can invalidate a cache that I use for the WebView content from the SettingsPageModel which would subsequently trigger the refresh, but then the SettingsPageModel needs to know about the cache.

What is the recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

One common way to send data between pages is with `MessagingCenter`.  It allows one page to subscribe to a string value, and run a method when another page sends that string value.  Here is how you can implement it:

In your mainPage you need to subscribe to the `MessagingCenter`

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<mainPage>(this, "updated profile", (sender) =>
{
    //Code to execute in main page when MessagingCenter triggered
});
```

The string value "update profile" is the key that the MessagingCenter is listening for.  Then when you put the following code in your Settings page, it will execute the code in the `MessagingCenter` of the `mainPage`:

```
MessagingCenter.Send((MainPage) mainPage, "updatedProfile");
```

Note: In order to get this to work, I had to send the `Page` value of my mainPage to the settings page.  To do this, in my settings page constructor I added a `Page` parameter:

```
public class SettingsPage : ContentPage {
    private Page mainPage;

    public SettingsPage(Page mainPage) {
        this.mainPage = mainPage;
    }
}
```

Then when Navigation to the `SettingsPage`, I sent my mainPage with it:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingsPage(this));
```

The documents for `MessagingCenter` can be found here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/